# calculating constant library functions at compile time

Tags: c++, constants, compile-time

I want to use boltzmann constant in my functions. I am using the following code to declare the boltzmann constant

```
const double boltzmann_constant = 1.3806503 * pow (10,-23);
```

Will this get calculated at the compile time itself? If now, how should i ensure that it does get calculated at compile time? Any other method to declare the constant?

Comment: I think it will be compile time in c++0x as it will make use of `constexpr`

Comment: ohk.... are c++0x standards still changing? 
last i read.. there was no guarantee that features would be preserved in the final standard... 
if constexpr stays in the final feature.. i might as well start using it in my production code.. not exactly in this case but in similar cases? 
what do you think?

Comment: I am not sure if math functions will be made constexpr or there will be a seperate set of functions returning constexpr values. But I can't think of why it should not be made so. You might consider asking this as another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pow()` function is very unlikely to be calculated at compile time.  However, the operation requested is directly expressible in scientific notation, a standard aspect of floating point numbers:

```
const double boltzmann_constant = 1.3806503e-23;
```

For a more complex situation, like `sin(M_PI / 3)`, it can be useful to write a program to calculate and display such values so they can be edited into a program.  If you do this, do everyone a favor and include a comment explaining what the constant is:

```
const double magic_val = 0.8660254037844385965883; // sin(M_PI / 3);
```

Comment: ohk... thanks... i was not sure about the floating point notation...
thank you

Comment: `0.86602540423628734624386` may not be same as `sin(M_PI / 3);` due to rounding errors.

Comment: @balki:  I used a low precision hand calculator originally.  I have now updated the value to be accurate (though the value displayed is hardly the point of my answer).

Comment: It is not about precision. Its about portablity. Sin(pi/3) will work in any compiler/architecture but 0.8660254037844385965883 may be too precise or less precise. If you are using another compiler which has a better precision and the code relies on this value to be equal to that, there is a potential bug.

Comment: @balki:  An excellent point!  In my 40 or so years working with floating point there has been no notable change how precision works, so I tend to think that 16+ significant digits will always be good enough.

Comment: Why isn't `pow()` likely to be calculated at compile time?

Comment: @endolith:  `pow()` is in a similar camp as `myfunc()`:  It is not something the compiler makes its business to evaluate constants at compile time.  The transcendental functions *could* be evaluated, but what if the user is not linking with the standard math library?  A custom math library might expect its arguments in, for example, gradian units, as expected by some surveyors.  So, in general, computing such expressions at compile time is not feasible.